# Error running tmux in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, tmux, shared-libraries

I have installed tmux through apt-cyg, but I keep getting this error when trying to run tmux:

`$ C:/cygwin64/bin/tmux.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygevent-2-0-5.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directorytmux.exe: error while loading shared libraries:`

Comment: Strange you get this, this worked fine for me and installed the missing libraries. Perhaps try using a different `apt-cyg` from one of the many forks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### error while loading shared libraries: cygevent-2-0-5.dll

You need to install [libevent](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibevent2.0_5%2Flibevent2.0_5-2.0.21-1&grep=cygevent-2-0-5.dll):

> libevent2.0_5: Event notification library (installed binaries and
>   support files)
>
> ```
> 2013-07-07 21:32      231443 usr/bin/cygevent-2-0-5.dll
> 2013-07-07 21:32      138259 usr/bin/cygevent_core-2-0-5.dll
> 2013-07-07 21:32      105491 usr/bin/cygevent_extra-2-0-5.dll
> 2013-07-07 21:32       20499 usr/bin/cygevent_openssl-2-0-5.dll
> 2013-07-07 21:32        9747 usr/bin/cygevent_pthreads-2-0-5.dll
> ```